# Query with lambda function in pymongo?

Tags: pymongo

I use the following query to fish for all men in a database:

```
f = pd.DataFrame(x for x in collection.find({"gender": "M"},{"_id":0}))
```

How could I find only the men where the "name" starts with an "A". Obviously I could filter the resulting huge DataFrame but how can I avoid creating this Frame in the first place.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MongoDB regular expression query, something like:

```
from bson.regex import Regex

f = pd.DataFrame(x for x in collection.find({"gender": "M", "name": Regex(r"^A.*")},{"_id":0}))
```